# Sorting array based on sequence

Tags: c#

I am trying to order an array in C#. The array contains currency codes like USD, EUR, GBP, CNY
The array has to be sorted in the following order of precedence: USD, EUR, GBP, CNY, alphabetical order

How do I sort based on that sequence

```
public class DerivativeTradeDto 
{
    public string SettlementCurrencyCode;
}
```

The `derivativeProvider.GetRccDerivativeTrades` returns an array of type
`DerivativeTradeDto`. The `SettlementCurrencyCode` contains the currency codes

```
var derivativesTrades = derivativeProvider
    .GetRccDerivativeTrades(uniqueId, runcContext)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I was trying for e.g OrderBy({"USD","EUR"})  but gives a compile error

Comment: So these are strings?

Comment: The array is of type custom class which has string member that contains these values

Comment: So the values and order of the first four are known and the rest are alphabetical?

Comment: @Tom You're making it very difficult to help you by not showing any code and not bothering to tell us what errors you're receiving.

Comment: I have updated the post with the code

Comment: Yes @ChiefTwoPencils. You are right

Comment: Implement [IComparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=netcore-3.1).  In your comparer, declare an array containing those special four codes in order.  If both codes are in that array, return a comparison of their locations in the array.  If one is in the array and the other is not, then just return a negative number to show the one from the array comes first.  If both are not in the array, then just return the result of an alphabetical comparison.

Comment: Please show assgnments of variables so we're all working with the same data. Where do you store the desired order of items, or how is it defined?

Comment: @Tom, updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a constant list to `OrderBy`

my approach would be

```
var orderOfPreference = new List<string> { "USD", "EUR", "GBP", "CNY" };
var orderedResults = derivativeTrades.OrderBy(d => {
                var index = orderOfPreference.IndexOf(d.SettlementCurrencyCode);
                return index == -1 ? int.MaxValue : index;
            }).ThenBy(x => x.SettlementCurrencyCode);
```

the `return index == -1 ? int.MaxValue : index` will place the not included in `orderOfPreference` outside of the index position of the list. `ThenBy` ensures it will arrange everything after the `orderOfPreference` alphabetically. you can change `int.MaxValue` by the length of data

Comment: Will it sort the ones that are not in the list in alphabetical order

Comment: ahh, i didnt read the whole, will update my answer

Comment: @Tom updated my answer